# Add field to a new JavaScript array copy

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JavaScript array which has the follow structure:

```
[{id:'id1', container:'3', routing:'4'},{id:'id2', container:'2', routing:'5'},..]
```

Now through the command 'push' i was able to make a copy of this array. My question is how to add a new element (NEWFIELD) to the new array, to become like this:

```
[{id:'id1', container:'3', routing:'4',NEWFIELD:'X'},{id:'id2', container:'2', routing:'5',NEWFIELD:'Y'},..]
```

Comment: How do you calculate or get the value of `newfield`?

Comment: Through division of other 2 fields. Something like NEWFIELD=routing/container. @nikhil

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{id:'id1', container:'3', routing:'4'},{id:'id2', container:'2', routing:'5'}];

 // clone an array
var newArr = arr.map(function(e) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e));
});

// add new field
newArr.forEach(function(e) {
    e['NEWFIELD'] = e.routing / e.container;
});

console.log(arr);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: His tag JSON confused me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like following

```
var arr = [{id:'id1', container:'3', routing:'4'},{id:'id2', container:'2', routing:'5'},..];

var new_arr = arr.map(function(item){
    var clone = Object.assign({}, item); // Objects are pass by referenced, hence, you need to clone object
    clone.NEWFIELD = clone.routing/clone.container;
    return clone;
});
```